# Writing items to file on separate lines without blank line at the end

Tags: python

I have a file with a bunch of text that I want to tear through, match a bunch of things and then write these items to separate lines in a new file.

This is the basics of the code I have put together:

```
f = open('this.txt', 'r')
g = open('that.txt', 'w')
text = f.read()
matches = re.findall('', text) # do some re matching here
for i in matches:
    a = i[0] + '\n'
    g.write(a)
f.close()
g.close()
```

My issue is I want each matched item on a new line (hence the '\n') but I don't want a blank line at the end of the file.

I guess I need to not have the last item in the file being trailed by a new line character.

What is the Pythonic way of sorting this out? Also, is the way I have set this up in my code the best way of doing this, or the most Pythonic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write out a sequence of lines with newlines between them, but no newline at the end, I'd use `str.join`. That is, replace your for loop with this:

```
output = "\n".join(i[0] for i in matches)
g.write(output)
```

In order to avoid having to close your files explicitly, especially if your code might be interrupted by exceptions, you can use the `with` statement to make things simpler. The following code replaces the entire code in your question:

```
with open('this.txt') as f, open('that.txt', 'w') as g:
    text = f.read()
    matches = re.findall('', text) # do some re matching here
    g.write("\n".join(i[0] for i in matches))
```

or, since you don't need both files open at the same time:

```
with open('this.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
matches = re.findall('', text) # do some re matching here
with open('that.txt', 'w') as g:
    g.write("\n".join(i[0] for i in matches))
```

Comment: +1, also, you might want to show @FusilliJerry the elegant power of the `with` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I have replaced the for loop as directed but now I get no output at all. Tried to print to console the result and I get nothing. Thoughts?

Comment: @FusilliJerry: What regex are you using?

Comment: Not to worry guys - got it sorted now. No idea what I did wrong when first implementing the suggested code but it is working perfectly the second time around. Thanks again. Any insights on the $with statement alluded to in this context @Tim Pietzcker?

Comment: Also, how did you make the with code statement highlighted in your comment (thought it might have been the addition of the $ symbol but no).

Comment: @FusilliJerry: I took the liberty of editing this answer instead of writing my own, since this is just an afterthought to the solution proposed here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Good edit. The only thing I might consider doing differently is splitting the one `with` into two. One would be at the top, with just the `read` call under it, and the other would be after the regular expressions and only contain the `write` call. They don't need to be nested, since you don't actually need both files open at the same time (like you might with code based purely on generators).

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. Really learning a lot here. @TimPietzcker would you mind writing out your code suggestion to make sure I have it right? Also, would still be keen to know how the 'with' was highlighted as a code block in the above comment ;)

Comment: Was going to start a new thread, but I have a question that relates to the above code (let me know if I should start a new thread though). What if I want to add some text to the start of each line being written to the file? For example, if the item being matched as i[0] above is 'hello' and I want 'really big hello' written to each line in the file instead of just 'hello'? Do I need to add more code to render this before using .join or can I use .join in this instance?

Comment: @FusilliJerry: I see you already asked the question in another thread and got a good answer. About the "highlighting": That's the standard code formatting feature: Surround the text by backticks (`).